# How to validate these inputs?

Tags: java, validation, input

I wrote a simple program.it gets two Integer number from user and return odd numbers to user.i validate them to force the user to type just Integer numbers.
when user type other data type,program gives him my custom error.that is right up to now but when this happen user has to type inputs from the beginning.it means that program takes the user to the first home.
here is my main class :

```
package train;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculate cal = new Calculate();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1 = 0;
        int number2 = 0;
        boolean isNumber;

        do {
            System.out.println("enter number1 please : ");
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                number1 = input.nextInt();
                isNumber = true;
                System.out.println("enter number2 please : ");
            }
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                number2 = input.nextInt();
                isNumber = true;

            } else {
                System.out.println("wrong number!");
                isNumber = false;
                input.next();
            }

        } while (!(isNumber));

        cal.setNumbers(number1, number2);
        cal.result();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

and here is my calculate class which return odd numbers :

```
public class Calculate {

    private int minNumber;
    private int MaxNumber;

    public void setNumbers(int min, int max) {
        this.minNumber = min;
        this.MaxNumber = max;
    }

    public void result() {
        int count = 0; // number of results
        ArrayList<Integer> oddNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // array of odd numbers

        // get odd numbers
        for (int i = minNumber; i < MaxNumber; i++) {

            if ((i % 2) != 0) {
                oddNumber.add(i);
                count++;
            }
        }

        int i = 0;// counter for printing array
        while (i < oddNumber.size()) {
            if(i != oddNumber.size()){
                System.out.print(oddNumber.get(i) + ",");
            }else{
                System.out.println(oddNumber.get(i));
            }
            i++;
        }

        // print result numbers
        System.out.println("\nResult number : " + count);

        // print number range
        System.out.println("You wanted us to search between " + minNumber
            + " and " + MaxNumber);

    }

}
```

Comment: However I found that accepted solution won't solve the asked problem as if second input is `non-integer` then again It will ask for the first input as well which was the actual problem. Still your accepted the answer so Correct me if I understood the question wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method `verifyAndGetNumber` which will verify a number with regex `\d+` which means match one or more digit. Throw Exception if it is not number. Catch the exception and print your custom message.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculate cal = new Calculate();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number1 = 0;
    int number2 = 0;
    boolean isNumber = false;

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("enter number1 please : ");
            if (input.hasNextLine()) {
                number1 = verifyAndGetNumber(input.nextLine());
            }

            System.out.println("enter number2 please : ");
            if (input.hasNextLine()) {
                number2 = verifyAndGetNumber(input.nextLine());
            }

            isNumber = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } while (!isNumber);

    cal.setNumbers(number1, number2);
    cal.result();
    input.close();
}

private static int verifyAndGetNumber(String line) throws Exception {
    if (line.matches("\\d+")) {
        return Integer.parseInt(line);
    }
    throw new Exception("wrong number!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of `Integer` inputs entered by the user and that way you can solve the problem.

So you can modify the code as:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculate cal = new Calculate();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1 = 0;
        int number2 = 0;
        boolean isNumber;
        int totalEnteredNumbers=0;
        int currNumber=1;
        do {
            System.out.println("enter number"+currNumber+" please : ");
            if (totalEnteredNumbers==0 && input.hasNextInt()) {
                number1 = input.nextInt();
                isNumber = true;
                currNumber++;
                System.out.println("enter number"+currNumber+" please : ");
                totalEnteredNumbers++;
            }
            if (totalEnteredNumbers==1 && input.hasNextInt()) {
                number2 = input.nextInt();
                isNumber = true;

            } else {
                System.out.println("wrong number!");
                isNumber = false;
                input.next();
            }

        } while (!(isNumber));

        cal.setNumbers(number1, number2);
        cal.result();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Anyways here you can also remove the `boolean` variable `isNumber` from termination condition by replacing it with `while(totalEnteredNumbers<2);`.

However this can also be solved with the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculate cal = new Calculate();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1 = 0;
        int number2 = 0;

        boolean numberTaken=false;

        while(!numberTaken)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number1 : ");
            String ip=input.next();
            try
            {
                number1=Integer.parseInt(ip); //If it is not valid number, It will throw an Exception
                numberTaken=true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Wrong Number!");
            }
        }

        numberTaken=false; //For second input

        while(!numberTaken)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number2 : ");
            String ip=input.next();
            try
            {
                number2=Integer.parseInt(ip); //If it is not valid number, It will throw an Exception
                numberTaken=true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Wrong Number!");
            }
        }
        cal.setNumbers(number1, number2);
        cal.result();
        input.close();
    }
}
```